# Mean Value theorem inequalities 2

Tags: calculus

Use the Mean Value Theorem to show that $|\log x - \log y| \leq |x - y|$ for any $x \geq  1$ and $y \geq 1$.

I had solved up to this point, but not sure
By applying the mean value theorem, Let $F(x) = \log x$ Suppose $x<y$, consider $\log x$ on $[x, y]$
$f'(c) = (\log x - \log y)/y-x$ since |f'(c)|is less than or equal to $1$
therefore, $|\log x - \log y| \leq |x - y|$

Answer (score 1):

$f(t)=\ln t\Rightarrow f'(t)=\frac{1}{t}$. Let $x\geq 1$ and $y\geq 1$ be two numbers with $x<y$. Then applying the MVT to $f(t)$ on the interval $[x, y]$ (Notice that $f$ is differentiable for all $x,\,y\geq 1$), we have
$f(y)-f(x)=f'(c)(y-x)$, or $\ln y-\ln x=\frac{1}{c}(y-x)$, where $c$ is a number in $1\leq x<c<y$. (This $c$ is guaranteed by the MVT). Since $c>1$, $\frac{1}{c}<1$. Thus we have $|\ln y-\ln x|\leq |y-x|$.